# Graphics.py Bouncing Cube

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I am trying to create a program that "bounces" a cube in a window up and down.  Everything is created properly but the cube will not bounce.

The code is as follows:

```
from graphics import *
import time # Used for slowing animation if needed
i=0

def create_win():
    win= GraphWin("Animation",500,500)
    cornerB1= Point(235,235)
    cornerB2= Point(265,265)
    Bob= Rectangle(cornerB1, cornerB2)
    Bob.setFill('blue')
    Bob.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
create_win()

def main():
    cornerB1= Point(235,235)
    cornerB2= Point(265,265)
    Bob= Rectangle(cornerB1, cornerB2)
    center= Rectangle.getCenter(Bob)
    center_point= Point.getX(center)
    for i in range(500):
        Bob.move(0,5)
        if center_point<15:
            dy= -dy
        elif center_point>485:
            dy= -dy

main()
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be too much code with too little planning.  Specific issues: you create Bob twice, once in each function -- the blue Bob you see isn't the Bob you're moving; too many numbers -- figure out your base dimensions and calculate everything else from them; you extract the center outside the loop so it never changes -- do it inside the loop so it's changing as Bob moves.

Below is a rework of your code that bounces Bob up and down as intended:

```
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500

BOB_SIZE = 30
BOB_DISTANCE = 5

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Animation", WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    # Create Bob in the middle of the window
    cornerB1 = Point(WIDTH/2 + BOB_SIZE/2, HEIGHT/2 + BOB_SIZE/2)
    cornerB2 = Point(WIDTH/2 - BOB_SIZE/2, HEIGHT/2 - BOB_SIZE/2)

    Bob = Rectangle(cornerB1, cornerB2)
    Bob.setFill('blue')
    Bob.draw(win)

    dy = BOB_DISTANCE

    for _ in range(500):
        Bob.move(0, dy)

        center = Rectangle.getCenter(Bob)
        centerY = Point.getY(center)

        # If too close to edge, reverse direction
        if centerY < BOB_SIZE/2 or centerY > HEIGHT - BOB_SIZE/2:
            dy = -dy

    win.close()

main()
```